# Create RTF file with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, rtf

I want to create an RTF file by creating my own source code of the RTF file and inserting in variables from my model.

I am creating the source coude using for example :

```
NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString stringWithString:"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang3084\deflangfe3084{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Calibri;}{\f2\froman\fprq2\fcharset2 Symbol;}}{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue255;}{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.10240}\viewkind4\uc1\trowd\trgaph70\trleft-108\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \trpaddl70\trpaddr70\trpaddfl3\trpaddfr3\clbrdrl\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrt\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrw10\brdrs \cellx2818\clbrdrl\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrt\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrw10\brdrs"];
```

I want this string to be saved as an RTF file and then the RTF reader will conver this code to a readable RTF File. The problem is that Xcode gives me numerous errors (unknown escape sequence) due to the characters such as * \d \c \g . Moreover it says "Incomplete universal character name".

How can I have my NSString be treated like source code and ignore all those errors so that it can be parsed in an RTF file.

Comment: I guess you are receiving errors because Apple has extended the RTF language but this is not representable with standard RTF. So, You will have to read [RTF Files and Attributed Strings] to understand Apple extension RTF commands.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/RTFAndAttrStrings.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your escape characters "\". When you write it to the console or file your string will output correctly.

```
NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\nouicompat\\deflang3084\\deflangfe3084{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\froman\\fprq2\\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\\f1\\fswiss\\fprq2\\fcharset0 Calibri;}{\\f2\\froman\\fprq2\\fcharset2 Symbol;}}{\\colortbl ;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;\\red0\\green0\\blue255;}{\\*\\generator Riched20 10.0.10240}\\viewkind4\\uc1\\trowd\\trgaph70\\trleft-108\\trbrdrl\\brdrs\\brdrw10 \\trbrdrt\\brdrs\\brdrw10 \\trbrdrr\\brdrs\\brdrw10 \\trbrdrb\\brdrs\\brdrw10 \\trpaddl70\\trpaddr70\\trpaddfl3\\trpaddfr3\\clbrdrl\\brdrw10\\brdrs\\clbrdrt\\brdrw10\\brdrs\\clbrdrr\\brdrw10\\brdrs\\clbrdrb\\brdrw10\\brdrs \\cellx2818\\clbrdrl\\brdrw10\\brdrs\\clbrdrt\\brdrw10\\brdrs\\clbrdrr\\brdrw10\\brdrs\\clbrdrb\\brdrw10\\brdrs"];
```